# Browse for excel file in R Shiny and open it in Microsoft Excel

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I would like to browse for files in R Shiny and open them in Microsoft Excel. I don't want to read them into R Shiny with read_exel or similar.

For now, I have a code to read in the files and display them in Shiny:

I already have a panel to browse the files:

```
    sidebarPanel(fileInput('browseFiles', 'View test description')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("inputFile")
    )
```

and a function:

```
    output$inputFile <- renderTable({

    inFile <- input$browseFiles
    
    if (is.null(inFile))
       return(NULL)
        
    read_excel(inFile$datapath, col_names = T, skip = 2)
 })
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You mean you want this app to list all files and folders to you, in a meaningful way, and then pick and choose from available xls(x) files and have them open in excel when you click it? Have a look at `shinyFiles` . Once you have that up and running to your liking, I guess you could do a `system(...)` call to start excel on your selected file

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem - thanks Sirius!

```
   sidebarPanel(shinyFilesButton('browseFiles', 'View', 'Select file', multiple = F)),
```

and

```
# Browse files with test description
 shinyFileChoose(input, 'browseFiles', root = c(Tests = pathTests), session = session,
                 defaultRoot = NULL,
                 # defaultPath = pathTests, 
                 filetypes=c('', 'xlsx'))

    
 observe({
    #print(input$browseFiles)
    
    # find path to data
    if(!is.integer(input$browseFiles)){
       p = parseFilePaths(roots = c(Tests = pathTests), input$browseFiles)
       
       # open the file
       if (.Platform$OS.type == "unix"){
          system(paste('open', as.character(p$datapath)))
       } else if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows"){
          system(as.character(p$datapath))
       }
    }
 })
```